# Django test can't find br tag

Tags: html, django-templates, django-unittest

I use linebreaks in template. But the test can't find 'br' tag.

```
{{ book.short_description | linebreaks }}
```

This is the test

```
self.assertContains(response, "New<br></br>Lines")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `html` to `True` in order to handle text as HTML:

```
self.assertContains(response, "New<br></br>Lines", html=True);
```

Or you can use [`assertHTMLEqual`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertHTMLEqual). I hope this will help.

Comment: get this instead AttributeError: 'HTMLParseError' object has no attribute 'msg'

Comment: It happens when the input HTML is not valid ! please try `"New<br>Lines` !!

Comment: I think you need to update to the last version of Django this bug is fixed just 10 days ago ! https://github.com/django/django/commit/d7a097265b1842843a73ce0da36ef98bacac8a3e